# ZeroMQ PUB/SUB and TCP transport

Tags: windows, tcp, named-pipes, zeromq

On Windows, I have to build a relatively simple topology in ZeroMQ.

I have a process (let's call it a bridge) that recieves data from outside and introduces them in the ZeroMQ topology. I'd like to use a set of publishers (something like `ipc:///bridge/entity1`, `ipc:///bridge/entity2`, `ipc:///bridge/entity3` and so on) but afaik, ZeroMQ does not support IPC transports on windows (due to the lack of named pipes in such OS).

So I've to move to a TCP transport, but I don't want to use one port for each entity: I'd like to use something like `tcp:///bridge:12345/entity1`, `tcp:///bridge:12345/entity2` and so on.

However AFAIK, [this is not possible with ZeroMQ](http://api.zeromq.org/2-1%3azmq-tcp).

Can you please point me to the right direction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's right, it's not possible to bind several ZeroMQ sockets to a single port.

Probably, your problem might be solved with a single PUB socket that publishes messages to different topics, and subscribers that connect with `zmq_setsockopt(ZMQ_SUBSCRIBE, ...)`. Since ZeroMQ 3.x topic filtering is done on PUB side, so there won't be redundant data transmission (related question: [ZeroMQ filtering at publisher](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13879261/zeromq-filtering-at-publisher/13881145#13881145))

Comment: That's what I was looking for. Is this approach suitable to NetMQ too? Indeed I have to use .NET. Or you suggest clrzmq?

Comment: @Giacomo Tesio: I don't have experience with MetMQ, but I'm sure it will work. Anyway, it takes a few minutes to give it a try. :)